# I am novice to Test Framework tools, Want to develope tests which I can integrate to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, automated-tests, googletest, boost-test

I want to develop Test frame work, which will run the executable  ( of the projects) and read the input and validate the value entered.

I was reading through gTest and Boost Test, from what I found is used to Module testing ( methods testing) . my purpose here is to System testing in which I have to run the executable and test the output entered. which I have to integrate into Jenkins eventually run as continuous Integration test model.

I would appreciate if anybody through light on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in order to give better answer please write your preferred development language.
Assuming Python, Java, C# is one of them i suggest you to use http://robotframework.org/.

There is a Jenkins plugin
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Robot+Framework+Plugin

I added images how Jenkins looks after running the test framework into Jenkins.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAiu7.png)

[image]

Also if you want to send this graph with the results in email please use:
https://github.com/oronboni/JellyBeanTemplates/blob/master/robot.groovy

(Assuming you already installed Email editable plugin).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using C++.  Basically I want to automate the unit testing ( System test). So I want to run the executable and that requires to read the user input and process it.